# looking for a more efficient method of describing a gridded rectangle so a robot can touch each point inside the rectangle

Tags: algorithm, lua, computercraft

I have been trying to code a solution for a robot to touch every point on a square or rectangular grid.

So far I have been working on a spiral solution that starts in the lower left and spirals in towards the centre and I have gotten it working and it appears to work on even(square) or uneven(rectangle) grids.

I wondered if the is a more efficient or elegant solution code-wise, than what I have below?

I'm pretty new to coding and I would love some feedback on how this code could be improved or if I'm missing a simpler mathematical solution etc.

e.g.: a 5 x 5 grid and [S] is the starting position spiralling toward position 25

```
[05][06][07][08][09]
[04][19][20][21][10]
[03][18][25][22][11]
[02][17][24][23][12]
[01][16][15][14][13]
[st]
```

at the moment my code looks like this and work ok. it does not need to be a spiral, it's just how the code currently works.

```
function MoveSides(depth, width) 
    local moving = true
    -- first set of instructions are set as variables and are updated after outer grid is touched
    local leftSide = depth -- for the first side turtle travels to full depth 
    local top = width - 1 -- turns and travels full width -1 as it is sitting on the first row
    local rightSide = depth -1 -- turns and does same coming back on depth
    local bottom = width -2 -- turns and travels width -2 having touched first and last space already

    while moving do
        for i = 1, leftSide do
    turtle.forward() -- move forward one space
        end
    turtle.turnRight()

        for i = 1, top do
    turtle.forward()
        end
    turtle.turnRight()

        for i = 1, rightSide do
    turtle.forward()
        end
    turtle.turnRight()

        for i = 1, bottom do
    turtle.forward()
        end
    turtle.turnRight()

    -- all sides loose 2 as the outers spaces have all been touched to describe next tier of grid.
    leftSide = leftSide -2
    top = top -2
    rightSide = rightSide -2
    bottom = bottom -2

        if (leftSide <= 0 and top <= 0 and rightSide <= 0 and bottom <= 0) then
    moving = false
        end

    end

end
```

Any help or constructive critique would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to touch every point in the grid there is nothing more efficient than to move from point to point, touching each point only once. That's what you're doing.

You can do it in a spiral or row- or column-wise or a mix of those. It does not matter as the number of movements is always the same.

The only difference is where your end point is.

Comment: sorry if I worded my question badly. when I said efficient I meant from a programming or algorithmic point. I get that my code goes from point to point but do we need all those loops. sometimes I see solutions to other problems that are so compact and efficient code wise and I wondered if the same was true here as my code feels bloated. also thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
function MoveSides(depth, width) 
   for i = 1, depth do
      turtle.forward() -- move forward one space
   end
   turtle.turnRight()
   if width > 1 then
      return MoveSides(width - 1, depth) 
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function MoveSides(depth, width) 
  current = depth
  other = width
  while current > 1 do
    for i = 1, current do
      turtle.forward()
    end
    turtle.turnRight()
    helper = current 
    current = other -1
    other = helper
  end
end
```

This solution is basically the same as Egor's recursive algorithm, but without a recurisive call.